# trouble with require_once failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, require, require-once

I'm getting the following error when trying to open the index file of a project that I am taking over on:

```
Warning: require_once(core_services/logging.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/docroot/www.website.com/index.php on line 7

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'core_services/logging.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/docroot/www.website.com/index.php on line 7
```

The code the error refers to looks like this:

```
7 require_once "core_services/logging.php";
8 $logger=new syslog_class(__FILE__,LOG_DEBUG);
```

I checked to make sure the filepath exists by defining it and echoing it back as well as the contents of `logging.php`in terminal and that returns just fine and when I get the current working directory on line 6, it returns `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/docroot/www.website.com`, which I am assuming is defining my root folder.

Not sure exactly how to go about resolving this problem and if anyone has any ideas on approach, I would love to hear them as my PHP is a bit rusty and lacking outside of the context of wordpress.

edit: approaches I've tried so far

```
require 'core_services/logging.php';
require '/core_services/logging.php';
require './core_services/logging.php';
require '../core_services/logging.php';
require '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/docroot/www.website.com/core_services/logging.php';
require realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/core_services/logging.php';
require(__DIR__"/../core_services/logging.php");

require_once 'core_services/logging.php';
require_once '/core_services/logging.php';
require_once './core_services/logging.php';
require_once '../core_services/logging.php';
require_once '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/docroot/www.website.com/core_services/logging.php';
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/core_services/logging.php';
require_once __DIR__"/../core_services/logging.php";
```

I have also verified that it is not a permissions issue.

Comment: Try `require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/core_services/logging.php';`

Comment: no luck on this approach, it returns the same error and just updating the attempted file path.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying full path:

```
require './core_services/logging.php';
//OR
require '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/docroot/www.website.com/core_services/logging.php';
```

Comment: Neither of those approaches work unfortunately. I get the same error only with updated file paths.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Mac actually, using XAMPP

Comment: Not sure about but could it be another file format/name ? I mean, all look good